# Adding Attribute to Core Data but can't get SQL file to match

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data-migration

Ok, so I changed the xcdatamodel to include a new attribute on all 3 new "tables" with a default value of 1.  I'm fairly new to Core Data, but very used to SQL and SQLite databases.  I clean the iphone simulator, build with the "special" options to addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType that do a light weight migration and presto it works.  I can change my Predicates to include this new attribute and it is fine.

I should note that I have an existing .sqlite file that is a resource for the project that gets copied to the app when compiled/run.  This sqlite file never changes on the iphone simulator.

I now need to take my existing rows of data and change some of these values to 2 or 3 for sorting and display purposes.  I was hoping the light weight migration would give me a new sqlite file that I could just copy back to a nice location, and use Navicat to change those values and overwrite the sqlite file in the xcode resource and remove the special options bit and be good.  However I dont get a new sql file, it does some other "magic" instead.

Since it looks like Core Data just takes attributes and adds Z to them I tried just added ZATTRIBUTENAME columns and using my new xcdatamodel file but I get the error  "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store".

I could care less that apple says not to edit these files with a SQL editor because it could screw things up. so please dont tell me your "not supposed to do that".  It isn't hard to tell what is going on in the core data scheme and sql.  The issue is I cannot get a new sqlite file to edit with the new attribute.

In short, I guess I am just trying to figure out how to get a new sqlite file generated by the new xcdatamodel that I can then copy and edit.  I've been researching this for a few days with little luck.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will forgive me for pointing out that "you are not supposed to do that". ;-)

Second, it seems you simply need to generate a new "seed" file to include in your application. Clearly, this file is not being changed. According to your description, it is not a core data file.

As for your new core data file after the migration, yes, it is a new file with a new data model and the old one is gone. You can certainly open that file and fiddle with it, or you can do it using core data in code.

This is how I do it: in your project, write some code simply for purpose of generating the new seed file (it could be core data, or just use the sqlite API), and disable or delete the code after you have successfully created the new version. This file you can now copy into your bundle and provide as a seed file.

Comment: hello, thanks for the quick reply.  As I said being new to this Core Data bit, it needs the xcdatamodel file to "understand" it in the code, doesn't that make it a core data file? I have no idea, someday I will :)What you are saying is insert like a "line" of data in to my tables to generate a new file? The lite migration doesn't do that for me.  Basically I need to just "start over"? Is that correct?

Comment: No. The migration will take care of updating the data model. You will have to update the data. If you have some seed data (text file, plist, xml file, sqlite database) you will have to copy this data by inserting it into your "seed" core data store as I described.

Comment: Sorry for expanding on this again.  I have a new sqlite database with the seed data in it.  It gives me an error "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" when I use this file.  If I use the original one, I don't get the error.   I guess when it comes down to it I have no idea how to do this.  Anyone available for hire to do this part? I won't be doing much more in terms of iPhone apps, and this is killing me.

Comment: Why don't you try what I recommended? Implement the import of the old data into the new model, say, in `AppDelegate.m`. Once it is done, deactivate the code. Now copy the new SQLite store to replace the old one.